# Website header widget on desktop has messed up mobile header

Tags: css, mobile

I recently added a widget to my website header for desktop mode. I struggled getting this widget to be on the same line and off to the right of the logo, but I eventually got it. In the process, it appears I messed up how the header looks on mobile devices (refer to twoguysplayingzelda.com for an example). Since 65% of my viewership is via mobile, I would like to fix this but have not figured out how. I would like the logo to be centered, completely view-able, and the menu icon on the left side (it use to be before I made the change). I am aware that I need to add coding into the responsive section of my style.css. Below is what I currently have for my header in CSS (desktop section). I knew nothing about CSS and HTML before I started my website, so I am still somewhat of a noob. Thanks for your help

```
div#header-widget-area {
  float: right;
}

.header { 
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  color: #01B3D9;
}

.header .cover { 
  background: rgba(29,29,29,0.0); 
}

.header-inner {
  position: relative; 
}

.header .blog-logo { 
  text-align: left; 
}

.header .logo { 
  display: inline; 
  float: left;
}

.header .logo img {
  max-height: 50px;
  width:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu icon is pushed to the right by the logo because they both have `float: left`.

Try to remove `float: left` from `.logo`, and add `display: inline-block` to `.blog-logo`. That should fix both of your issues.

Comment: Some of that did work. Thanks! Now I am having an issue with extra padding in my header section for desktop mode. How can I reduce the header size. I tried padding-top and padding-bottom in a couple different places with no luck. Lastly, I don't want to show the widget in the header for mobile. I had the below code that used to work but it doesn't anymore.

    @media (max-width: 600px)

    div#header-widget-area {
     display: none;
    }

Comment: @TwoGuysPlayingZelda I took a look at your site and seems you've removed the widget. Have you solved the padding issue as well?

Comment: I ended up removing the widget for now after messing up the design of my website. Something would work in one view (desktop) but it wouldn't work in another (mobile). I am going to tackle some other priorities I had and come back to this. I will be sure to use your information. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @TwoGuysPlayingZelda if my answer works for the problem that you asked in your original question, can you please accept it? Good luck with your site!